# Selecting distinct values in a joined table

Tags: mysql

Simplifying the problem I'm tackling somewhat, but I think the following is the gist of it:

I have two tables (TableA and TableB), joined by a LEFT JOIN.

I need to get ten records from TableA in reverse chronological order; but with each of those ten results having a unique value in TableB.foo.

i.e.

A.id is 1, A.date is two days ago, B.foo is 'cat'.
A.id is 2, A.date is yesterday, B.foo is 'cat'.
A.id is 3, A.date is today, B.foo is 'dog'.
A.id is 4, A.date is three days ago, B.foo is 'pig'.
A.id is 5, A.date is four days ago, B.foo is 'dog'.

I'd want the top 3 results of my query to be 3,2,4 (and 1 and 5 not to be returned at all).

Can this be achieved in a single MySQL query?

Failing that, what would be the most efficient strategy for getting the desired resultset in multiple steps?

Comment: What is the join parameter for the two tables? this looks fairly simple.

Comment: What columns are you joining by?

Comment: Yeah, I may have oversimplified the actual problem, but better that than the reverse (maybe)!  Let's say for the sake of argument right now it's LEFT JOIN ON a.b_id = b.id.

Comment: Are you sure it should be a LEFT JOIN? Which table is allowed to have no corresponding rows from the other? It can't be B, because you want to group by unique B.foo. But if it's A, what date should it sort by and what id should be shown?

Comment: Hmm, yes, I guess you're right Barmar and it should be an INNER JOIN.  As realistically I can't do much that's sensible with no value for B.foo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.date
FROM (SELECT A.id id, B.foo foo, A.date date
      FROM A JOIN B
      ON A.b_id = B.id) T1
JOIN (
    SELECT B.foo foo, MAX(A.date) maxdate
    FROM A JOIN B
    ON A.b_id = B.id
    GROUP BY B.foo) T2
ON T1.foo = T2.foo and T1.date = T2.maxdate
ORDER BY T1.date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Add a `LIMIT 10` and this should meet his requirements.

Comment: Looks cool, I will try this approximate plan out tomorrow morning and accept if it meets the requirements!

Comment: Thanks, the logic is right and my question is answered!  Now to try and work out if there's any way I can tame the monster query I've ended up with to something less incredibly slow and clunky...