# Taming a monster MySQL query

Tags: mysql, cakephp

So with a little bit of help from kind SO users, I've ended up with a logically correct MySQL query for a task I'm working on: retrieving a reverse-chronologically ordered list of ids for news items permitted to a user, with certain types of grouped items filtered down to a single representative of that group.  (Phew!)

The obvious problem remaining is that this query is immensely clunky and slow - according to CakePHP's debug printout of database calls, to the tune of 145000 ms, ouch.

Is there a sensible approach to taming a beast like this one, or should I admit I'm biting off more than I can chew here, and look for a less ponderous approach that will achieve more or less similar results?  All suggestions appreciated.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Uid.id, Uid.type
    FROM (SELECT uids.id id, uids_uids.parent_id parent_id, uids.created date,
                 uids.type type
          FROM uids 
          JOIN uids_uids ON uids_uids.uid_id = uids.id
          JOIN aros_uids ON uids.id = aros_uids.uid_id
          JOIN uids_uids ParentUids ON uids_uids.parent_id = ParentUids.uid_id
          WHERE uids.type IN ('Document','Photo','Release','PreRelease',
                              'ArtworkResource','Event') 
            AND (uids.start_date IS NULL OR uids.start_date <= NOW())
            AND (uids.end_date IS NULL OR uids.end_date <= NOW())
            AND aros_uids.aro_id IN (3,2,86,1448)
          ) Uid
    JOIN (SELECT uids_uids.parent_id parent_id, MAX(uids.created) maxdate
          FROM uids JOIN uids_uids
          ON uids_uids.uid_id = uids.id
          GROUP BY uids_uids.parent_id, uids.type) T2
    ON Uid.parent_id = T2.parent_id AND Uid.date = T2.maxdate
    ORDER BY Uid.date DESC
    LIMIT 100
```

**ETA:**

Okay, as a first pass, I turned those subselects into Views, so now the query looks like a slightly more manageable

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Uid.id, Uid.type
    FROM UidView Uid
    JOIN UidView2 T2
    ON Uid.parent_id = T2.parent_id AND Uid.date = T2.maxdate
    WHERE Uid.aro_id IN (3,2,86,1448)
    ORDER BY Uid.date DESC
    LIMIT 100
```

This has definitely helped, reducing Cake's estimated query time in ms from six figures to 2500 or so.  Definitely a good start!

Comment: I'll give you one thing - thats a lot of 'uids' to look at in one query and get your head around...

Comment: @nickhar Tell me about it! In my defence I didn't set any of this up, I'm just trying to slowly wrestle it into a manageable state.  Every item on the site has a uid which is connected to other uids by a uids_uids table.  There's a lot of "WHERE uids_uids.uid_id = uid.id" type stuff going on :)

Comment: You have my sympathies. A uid_uid table!? Nice. I'd capture that structure and submit it to coding horrors.

Comment: First things first, have you run an MYSQL explain against the query to make sure you are maximizing the efficiency of your indexes?

Comment: @RichardAtHome, yeah, someone else suggested to start with that and then deleted the answer.  My problem is that I an see the results of the EXPLAIN but don't really know what to do with them.  There are a fair few indexes, some of which are being used...

Comment: Indexing 101: Put an index on any field that references another table (foreign key), but an index on any field in a where clause. if a where clause uses multiple fields, put a combined index on all of them.

Comment: Another option is (a lazy-man's solution) - leave the query as-is, improve the caching of the results. It won't help you understand MySQL better, but it could do the trick, at least until you figure out how to optimize DB better. Could you post the initial question, which yielded this query?

Comment: @VanjaD. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846995/selecting-distinct-values-in-a-joined-table/12847703#12847703

Comment: While MySQL doesn't support it, window functions [PARTITIONed BY parent_id, type ORDERed BY created] would handle this more naturally and possibly more efficiently.  This type of windowing operation can be done in MySQL with an outer join.  The outer join approach may also be more efficient in some cases.

Comment: @nickhar - agreed. coding horrors or thedailyWTF.com. It would sit nicely on either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try:

Take each derived query and run an `EXPLAIN` against each separately. As the comments suggest, check for any lines that are missing indexes and add when needed. Post your `EXPLAIN` results for any help. So

```
EXPLAIN SELECT uids.id id, uids_uids.parent_id parent_id, uids.created date, ....
EXPLAIN SELECT uids_uids.parent_id parent_id, MAX(uids.created) maxdate ....
```

If adding indexes doesn't help or help much, then put each subquery into a temp table first and apply indexes to it:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_uid
SELECT uids.id id, uids_uids.parent_id parent_id, uids.created date,
             uids.type type
      FROM uids 
      JOIN uids_uids ON uids_uids.uid_id = uids.id
      JOIN aros_uids ON uids.id = aros_uids.uid_id
      JOIN uids_uids ParentUids ON uids_uids.parent_id = ParentUids.uid_id
      WHERE uids.type IN ('Document','Photo','Release','PreRelease',
                          'ArtworkResource','Event') 
        AND (uids.start_date IS NULL OR uids.start_date <= NOW())
        AND (uids.end_date IS NULL OR uids.end_date <= NOW())
        AND aros_uids.aro_id IN (3,2,86,1448);

CREATE TABLE temp_t2
SELECT uids_uids.parent_id parent_id, MAX(uids.created) maxdate
      FROM uids JOIN uids_uids
      ON uids_uids.uid_id = uids.id
      GROUP BY uids_uids.parent_id, uids.type;
```

And `JOIN` on those tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Uid.id, Uid.type
FROM temp_uid AS Uid
JOIN temp_t2 AS T2 ON Uid.parent_id = T2.parent_id AND Uid.date = T2.maxdate
ORDER BY Uid.date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

As I mentioned, you'll probably have to add indexes, and probably to these columns in the temp tables:

```
ALTER TABLE temp_uid ADD INDEX parentDateIdx (parent_id, Uid.date);
ALTER TABLE temp_t2 ADD INDEX parentMaxDateIdx (parent_id, maxdate);
```

If you need to refresh the temp tables, just truncate them and perform an `INSERT INTO temp_uid...SELECT` and `INSERT INTO temp_t2...SELECT` on them, instead of a `CREATE...SELECT`. A stored procedure works great for this.

btw, performing a `CREATE TABLE temp_t2...SELECT`, the way I did for each temp table, may not create an optimal table structure, so it might be better to modify the create afterward or do it yourself from scratch.

Comment: Cheers, this looks like a sensible approach.  I tried something similar but with views instead of tables.  Is CREATE TABLE likely to yield better results?

Comment: I believe it should, especially when you add indexes to those temp table's columns. You really need to test it out though to be sure. And don't neglect adding indexes to all those uid's table as well. Here are the docs on my create table example [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) and insert...select [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)